# Retrieving value of inner promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, location, promise, angular-promise

I am trying to access the value of a nested promise from a controller.

Here is my **controller**. I am calling my **service**, expected a city name to be returned:

```
LocationService.getCurrentCity(function(response) {
    // This is never executed
    console.log('City name retrieved');
    console.log(response);
});
```

And here is the **service**. I am updating the position of the client, and then I request the city from Google. The `console.log(city)` **do** log the correct city as expected.

```
this.getCurrentCity = function() {
    return this.updateMyPosition().then(function() {
        return $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + myPosition.lat + ','+ myPosition.lng +'&sensor=false').then(function(response) {
            var city = response.data['results'][0]['address_components'][3]['long_name'];
            console.log(city);
            return city;
        });
    });
}
```

How can I access the `city` in my controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a promise and should unwrap it with `then`:

```
LocationService.getCurrentCity().then(function(response) {
    // This is never executed
    console.log('City name retrieved');
    console.log(response);
});
```

Promises work by using return value just like synchronous values - when you call `getCurrentCity` it is returning a promise which you can unwrap using `then`.

Comment: @Maeh you're welcome - not enforcing the number of arguments functions take is an annoying property of JS. A good static analysis tool can really go a long way in finding these annoying bugs.